# Info lightbutton animation

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uianimation

I am having trouble in showing `infobutton` to navigate to information page/view.

I have written this code.

```
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
UIBarButtonItem *infoButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
toolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButtonItem, nil];
```

I got `infolight` button but i do not now know how to do animate & navigation action method in to flip to info page.

I also want infobutton to stay at center, currently it is at left corner.

Answer (score 1):

```
This will create ur info button in center.
UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    UIBarButtonItem *infoButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
    [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToRechercherView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleLeft,infoButtonItem,flexibleLeft, nil];


This is for swipe animation. add your view inside.
-(void)goToRechercherView{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                           forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it`s working.

I have added flipviewcontroller.h .m .xib to project,so when i click on info button i want to go to that page.

do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this...

First one is......

```
newView setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)]; //notice this is OFF screen!
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[newView setFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)]; //notice this is ON screen!
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Second option is to use built in animations as flip and curl:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                               forView:newView
                                cache:YES];

    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:settingsView.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```